# Laravel 5.4 call to undefined function Session::getMetadataBag()

Tags: laravel

In version 5.3, Session::getMetadataBag() was working good to fetch the Session data but after upgrade it is throwing error as Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getMetadataBag()

Session::all() doesn't carry last use record like below:

```
array:4 [
    "_token" => "SQjQpOxCec5lal5tzFgW1FMtrcOaaIqjoii2fuCb"
    "_previous" => array:1 [
        "url" => "http://my-url"
    ]
    "_flash" => array:2 [
        "old" => []
        "new" => []
    ]
    "lang" => "en"
]
```

while Session::getMetaDataBag carries below record:

```
MetadataBag {#582
    -name: "__metadata"
    -storageKey: "_sf2_meta"
    #meta: & array:3 [
        "u" => 1485527838
        "c" => 1485527838
        "l" => "0"
    ]
    -lastUsed: 1485527838
    -updateThreshold: 0
}
```

Any alternative to get this lastUsed record in Laravel 5.4?

Comment: How did you solved this I have the same problem

Comment: How did you solved this I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The metadatabag is actually part of Symfony. In Laravel 5.4, the session component was refactored to not depend on Symfony anymore, so the metadatabag is gone. You will need to implement this functionality yourself.

Comment: Can you help me how to write this function