# How to get session metadata in laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to get last activity time from session metadata in Laravel 5.6 but it seems it is removed after Laravel 5.4.

Code to get session metadata which is now not working:

```
Session::getMetaDataBag();
```

Is there any alternative to get these information?

Comment: Are you actually using the Database to store sessions?

Comment: @LeenaPatel No, using file storage. Does that make difference?

Answer (score 0):

> The metadatabag is actually part of Symfony. In Laravel 5.4, the session component was refactored to not depend on Symfony anymore, so the metadatabag is gone. You will need to implement this functionality yourself.

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/41898253/7182677

You can allways use `Session::all()` or `Session::get('key')`.

Comment: Yes, I know but I am asking about alternatives. As stated in question link you added, Session::all() doesn't carry last use record.

Comment: well for laravel 5.7 i don't think there's a function that sweet your needs, but someone has already mentioned it in the laravel 6 wishlist.